# thymeleaf th:if - Cannot index into a null value

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

thymeleaf `index.xhtml` -

> EL1012E: Cannot index into a null value

```
<div class="mylist" th:each="row,rowStat : *{dataList}">
   Folder: <span th:text="*{dataList[__${rowStat.index}__].folderName}" />
   <div class="invalid-feedback"
        th:if="${dataList[__${rowStat.index}__].folderName == appFolderName}">                           
        Folder already exists. Please choose different folder name.
   </div>
</div>
```

It is displaying the folderName but not validating `th:if` and `appFolderName` is a model attribute [dynamic value].

Comment: You've been using `*{dataList` but in your `th:if` you use `${dataList`.

Comment: I am not able to recreate your error using your code, as long as there are no null values in my Java `dataList`. Your code works correctly for me, including the `if` statement.

Comment: If you already have a `row` variable from your `th:each` expression, why do you need to index into `dataList` using `rowStat`? Why can you not use `${row.folderName}` instead? Or, given you are using SpEL, why not use `${row?.folderName}` to [safely navigate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation) any null values in your list?

Comment: Thanks @andrewJames, I am new to this code base, I read the documentation but could not grasp much as I had a less time. It worked with `th:if="${row.folderName} == ${appFolderName}"`. Please feel free to post it as answer and correct me with syntax and suggest best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `th:each="row,rowStat : *{dataList}"` iterator, I would simplify that code to this:

```
th:each="row : ${dataList}"
```

You can think of this as being broadly equivalent to the following Java for-loop:

```java
List<DataItem> dataList = ...; // assume this is populated with DataItems

for (DataItem dataItem : dataList) {
    System.out.println(dataItem.getFolderName());
}
```

In the above for-loop, we do not need to access the list by index - and the same is also true for the Thymeleaf syntax.

---

Thymeleaf lets you access fields in an object without needing to refer to the getter method.

So, now that we have our `row` variable from `th:each="row : ${dataList}"`, we can do this:

```
<div class="mylist" th:each="row,rowStat : *{dataList}">
    Folder: <span th:text="${row.folderName}" />
    <div class="invalid-feedback"
         th:if="${row.folderName == appFolderName}">                           
        Folder already exists. Please choose different folder name.
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, you can see `${row.folderName}` - which means Thymeleaf will invoke the `getFolderName()` method on the `row` object. This relies on your object using JavaBean naming standards for your getters.

---

You can enhance the Thymeleaf `th:each` processor by adding a second variable - which is what you do in your question: `rowStat`:

```
th:each="row,rowStat : ${dataList}"
```

This gives you access to extra information about the status of the Thymeleaf iterator - you can see a list of all these extra data values [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#keeping-iteration-status).

These extra values are no needed in your case. But they can be useful in other situations - for example if you want to identify the `first` or `last` record in the list, or all `even` records, and so on.

---

Your example in the question uses the `__${...}__` [preprocessing syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#preprocessing) - which is very powerful and can be extremely useful. But again, it is not needed for your basic functionality.

---

Your example uses both `${...}` and `*{...}` syntaxes to create Thymeleaf variables. It's important to understand the basic differences between them.

The difference is covered in the documentation describing the [asterisk syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#expressions-on-selections-asterisk-syntax):

> the asterisk syntax evaluates expressions on selected objects rather than on the whole context. That is, as long as there is no selected object, the dollar and the asterisk syntaxes do exactly the same. And what is a selected object? The result of an expression using the th:object attribute.

The documentation has examples.

---

Finally, because you are using Spring (as per the tag in your question), then you are actually using Spring's dialect of Thymeleaf and SpEL - the [Spring Expression Language](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions).

This is broadly similar to the standard (OGNL) expression language used by the standard (non-Spring) Thymeleaf dialect - but it has several very useful enhancements.

One such enhancement is the [safe navigation operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation) I mentioned in my comment:

```
${row?.folderName}
```

Here, the `?` will immediately return `null` if `row` is `null`. Without this, you would get a null pointer exception when Thymeleaf attempted to invoke the `getFolderName()` method on a null `row` object.